# Minikube start fails to create VM

Tags: windows, kubernetes, minikube, hyper-v

I am trying to start Minikube but it fails at the creation of the VM.
Last Thursday it was working fine, but Friday, I tried to start it while using a VPN (cisco), and it didn't work well (which seems to be a well-known problem with Cisco), so I tried to mess with some network settings, change the Minikube version... without success

But now, even without the VPN it doesn't work. I tried to disable and reenable Hyper-V, uninstall and reinstall Minikube but no changes.

In the logs, I see that the creation of the VM blocks on this line

```
    I1017 09:50:30.831122   12020 main.go:134] libmachine: [stderr =====>] :
I1017 09:50:30.832236   12020 main.go:134] libmachine: [executing ==>] : C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -NonInteractive [Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8; ConvertTo-Json @(Hyper-V\Get-VMSwitch|Select Id, Name, SwitchType|Where-Object {($_.SwitchType -eq 'External') -or ($_.Id -eq 'c08cb7b8-9b3c-408e-8e30-5e16a3aeb444')}|Sort-Object -Property SwitchType)
```

Any ideas where this might come from ? Thanks

Comment: Add the message that you get when you run minikube start

Comment: It was stuck on "Creation of the hyperv VM", and then a timeout message.
But after futher investigations, it seems to be a HyperV VMSwitch problem. 
The Get-VMSwitch returns a "Generic failure"
This error has nothing to do with Minikube, it's an HyperV problem

Answer (score 0):

I think I was able to reproduce your issue.

Try with `minikube delete --all` and `minikube delete --purge` and start again your minikube increasing the cpus and memory.

`minikube config --driver=hyperv` and
`minikube start --driver=hyperv --cpus 2 --memory=4078`

Comment: I tried that, but same result
As stated abobe, the error seems to come from Hyper-V instead of Minikube

Comment: I updated my response. Please, try to increase the number of CPUs and memory. First, delete your minikube with minikube delete and start once again. If that works please, consider this response as the final solution.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, it was a Windows problem. I messed up with the device manager and probably ended up damage some windows components, damaging the hyperv service. I reinstalled Windows and it is working fine now